# Sort data frame in ascending order by mean of other column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I have a data frame:

```
df = 

ID  Num
a   3
b   4
b   2
a   1
```

Want to sort in ascending order by taking into account unique values of `ID` column

---

My Try:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Num'])
```

But it gave me ascending order by neglecting `ID` column

---

Desired output:

```
df = 

ID  Num
a   1
a   3
b   2
b   4
```

Comment: `df.sort_values(by=['ID','Num'])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
df.sort_values(['ID', 'Num'])
```

**Output**

```
  ID  Num
3  a    1
0  a    3
2  b    2
1  b    4
```